# What's the easiest way to refresh Entity Model after adding/deleting DB fields?

Tags: entity-framework

Does anyone know what the esiest way to update the entity model after adding/deleting the fields in the database?

I am adding a few new fields to my database, then choose "Update Model from DB" and nothing happens. The model stays intact. Did anyone encounter the same problem?

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EF that shipped for .net 3.5 I tend to follow the following steps:

1. Delete the connectionstring
2. Delete the model
3. Generate a new model
4. Build solution

This is perhaps not a very solid approach but it saves me time in the long run. In the future it is easier and more stable to do a refresh but I have gone from autogenerating my model to model-first.

Comment: yep, so basically the same thing I do.
looks like there is no other solution, except deleting the model and regenerating it.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely check out the EDM Generator which allows you to do a full generation of the model from scratch - [Click here to go to the MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387165.aspx).  It has saved me a lot of time and hope it will do the same for you.